# system2("open","/Users/folder (P)") results in " syntax error near unexpected token `(' " in R

Tags: r, directory, parentheses

trying to open folder using R by the code

```
 system2("open","/Users/folder (P)"）
```

results in error A below

```
 sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

i think it is because the folder name has parentheses. looking forward to help and any comments are welcome

I tried the below code too--

```
 system2("open","/Users/folder \(P\)"）
```

then error B is

```
 Error: '\(' is an unrecognized escape in character string
```

I also tried hitting Tab button, then successfully selecting the "folder (P)", but it results in the same error A

Comment: You're missing a closing paren. Try: `system2("open","/Users/folder (P)")`

Comment: it won't work with closing parentheses either, thanks though

Comment: If you look at the closing parenthesis in your code, it is in a strange character(unless it's just my eyes). Plus is that path correct anyways?

Comment: i didn't type the path, i hit tab and select the "folder (P)" from the results searched by R, still not working.
So I believe the path is right otherwise R should not be able to find it and show it as the option list to select

Comment: Try running this: `system2("open","/Users")`. This works for me. Your closing parenthesis(ok, I prefer the word bracket) is not correct. Your path also seems weird. Using Tab also seems like a bad idea, the path generated has some issues at least for me especially if the folder name has some spaces for instance.

Comment: i tried, without folder name containing bracket in the directory, it works just fine.
the folder is actually dropbox business folder, dropbox forces to give names like "dropbox (Harvard)"

Comment: Just escape it like so : `\\(P\\)`. Can't test, no such folder name on my PC, don't want to create one either. XD

Comment: tested, not working...thanks though